# How to connect Jenkins with Google Cloud Shell particularly for GKE

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, continuous-integration, google-kubernetes-engine

i am working on integrating **jenkins** on **Google Kubernetes**. Want a pipeline for my project which will perform following steps:

- Build JAR from maven
- Build docker image and push to google registry
- **kubectl apply -f** commands or **Helm commands** to run for redeploys,upgrade, downgrade etc

I am familiar with above commands individually but i am new to this type of pipeline where i can run them but everytime jenkins try to teach me that you are in a container, not on kubernetes lol

I have a google cloud shell and i cannot directly install on that machine. So i have to somehow find a way to integrate jenkins to pass those commands directly to GKE environment.

i just want a proper step by step guide for anyone not familiar with how to achieve following points:

> - Have GKE
> - Have jenkins pod on it
> - Know all commands to execute (docker, gcloud, kubectl, helm etc)
> - **Just need an integration between jenkins and GKE to utilize all above**

Kindly bear me if i am unable to explain that much. Ask anything else you need to resolve this. Thank

Answer (score 1):

If your Jenkins pod is running inside GKE, just go for [accessing the api from a pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod) and wrap your last step into small python/go script.

If you prefer to use `kubectl` you could:
set up correct rbac, for example (this one allow to list pods and servies):

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: list
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["services", "pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "list"]

---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: list
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: svc-list
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

and then

```
kubectl run --restart=Never --rm -it ubuntu --image ubuntu:18.04
```

```
{
   apt-get update
   apt-get install -y apt-transport-https curl gnupg
   curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg |  apt-key add -

  cat <<EOF | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
EOF

   apt-get update
   apt-get install -y kubectl
}
```

`kubectl get po,svc`

```
NAME         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/ubuntu   1/1     Running   0          16m

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   122d
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. BTW isn't it an overhead? i mean why i go to that scripts or rest API? Can't i just establish a connection somehow with GKE and run those simple kubectl commands directly which i am used to and save my life? Is there something i missing? am i having wrong approach in my mind?

Comment: sorry for my less knowledge. i have done this and it made a pod and telling all the information i required through kubectl. Fair enough. Now i will install jenkins on this ubuntu image and i am good to create the pipelines?  All the shell scripts then have simply kubectl commands and they will run perfectly, right?

Comment: No, you have to install kubectl in your jenkins pod.

Comment: At this time when i run simple command, it shows bellow error. 

**kubectl get pods**
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default"

Comment: Check my answer `set up correct rbac, for example (this one allow to list pods and servies):`

Comment: i have already applied that. do i have to redeploy my pod to update changes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197734/discussion-between-vicky-and-fl3sh).